# Powershell Search-UnifiedAuditLog

Tags: powershell, office365

Our old script usic Basic authentication to read the O365 Logs doesn't work anymore as MS stopped Basic Authentication. Quite normal.

We would like to rewrite the script using the cmdlet Search-UnifiedAuditLog, that seems to be part of ExchangePowerShell.

But after installing tat module with Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement the search cmdlet is not yet available.
Also the Get-Command show far more less cmdlets then the documentation does.

I'm not a Powershell export, could somebody help me out what I'm doing wrong ?

Kr, Harry

Comment: I haven't worked with EXO for a while, but I'm pretty sure you need to call `Connect-ExchangeOnline` after importing the module - it'll connect to O365 and import the remote session into your host, thus giving you the remaining commands. Try [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/connect-to-exchange-online-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: To login in a HTTPS Request you need to setup  the HTTPS headers and body.  It is the same in Powershell as other applications like java.   See the JAVA setup at following : https://dev.to/john_mason_1639504125deba/office-365-authentication-and-authorization-with-asp-net-core-web-api-and-with-a-separate-javascript-frontend-1ah9?force_isolation=true

Answer (score 0):

As posted this surely was the solution, Thx Mathias